# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (datetime) specified for Class

Tags: django, datetime

So I have a class named InputArticle, and have a field named 'created' and 'modified.' 
Below is my code in models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.utils import timezone

class InputArticle(models.Model)
    # other fields
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField()
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.created:
            self.created = timezone.now()
        self.modified = timezone.now()
        return super(InputArticle, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

However when I try to do python `manage.py makemigrations` I keep getting this error that says: 
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (datetime) specified for InputArticle 
I have no idea on what the problem is. 
I very much appreciate your help :)

Comment: Try this `created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)` and `modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)`. Parameter auto_now_add will add time only once(i.e whenever first object gets created) and it is by default non-editable which is great for created field, Parameter auto_now will update timestamp value whenever the object gets updated so it will be great choice for modified field. You can read it over here [Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/datetimefield-django-models/)

Comment: Thanks. So then would it be inappropriate to use that function ```save```?

Comment: Yes, save() can be used to validate the values before saving it into db. Currently for those 2 fields timezone is automatically setting up, no need to override save() unless you have to check something.

Comment: Well I've done it, but I still get the exactly same error :( What do you think is the problem?

Comment: Do you have any other fields other than these two fields ? Named as datetime or something which use date time ? (Also make sure you don't have editable parameter set atlest for created and modified field)

Comment: Well no, I don't have any other datetime fields aside from those two. may be should I try shutting down and restarting?

Comment: Well I don't think restarting server will solve the problem, still give it a try. Also can you post your entire model and the errors you are getting while migrating ? It will be helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210138/discussion-between-ryan-oh-and-k33da-lets-debug).